# Excel FindNext не работает

Tags: c#, excel

Не работает функция FindNext. Исходный текст взял на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e4x1k99a.aspx). Игрался с параметрами Find. Не помогает. Find находит первый элемент диапазона, а FindNext всегда возвращает null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял, почему этот пример не работает для меня. Пришлось немного модифицировать его. Почитав документацию, можно узнать что параметр FindNext должен принимать одиночную ячейку (хотя вроде Find также возвращает одиночную ячейку).

```
//Мы модифицируем данную строку
currentFind = Fruits.FindNext(currentFind); 
//В итоге получается нечто похожее на
currentFind = Fruits.FindNext(currentFind.Cells[1, 1]);
```

Может кому пригодится.